# Do grad students in the USA typically have more or less student debt than undergrads?

Tags: graduate-school, funding, united-states, undergraduate, salary

A student advocate at my institution recently claimed that grad students have more debt than undergrads. This surprised me, because I would expect that typical grad students are the kind of student that would be able to gather more financial aid (scholarships, awards, fellowships, etc.) during their time as an undergrad than typical undergrads. Furthermore, most PhD students (and many masters students) have their tuition waived while working as a TA/RA, so they accrue little/no additional debt. Of course, this likely varies with field, too: students in STEM are more likely to have institutional funding while law or medical students often have to pay their own way.

While I don't know if the statistic I quoted was comparing undergrads who haven't yet accrued their full measure of debt to grads who have all of their undergrad debt, it begs an interesting question:

**Do undergraduate students typically have more student debt than graduate students have, and (broadly) how does this vary with field of study?**

The comparison ought to be made after each group graduates from their respective program, since comparing a 1st year undergraduate's debt to a 1st year PhD student's debt clearly would not be helpful.

Comment: Well, grad students may not be taking out students loans but they are likely not paying down their loans from undergrad, which may be accruing interest.

Comment: I'm sure it varies wildly with field of study and individual.  I took out a small subsidized (i.e. no interest while I'm in school) loan as an undergrad that I will need to pay back when I graduate from my PhD, but grad school has cost me nothing but lost opportunity. In fact, I'll be a bit in the black overall since the cost of living in my city is so cheap.  My MD & Lawyer friends will be in debt for years from their student loans, and though their salary will be higher, their lifestyle demands will also be more expensive, so I may still come out "ahead" (financially).

Comment: @AustinHenley - They should not be accruing interest, if the individuals have done their paperwork correctly.

Comment: @aparente001 Unsubsidized loans (like mine) begin accruing interest immediately.

Comment: @AustinHenley - You're kidding.  You can't defer payment while you are a full-time student?!

Comment: @aparente001 You don't have to make payments as a student but the interest is being applied. So yes, it's deferred but the amount is growing.

Comment: @AustinHenley - Good heavens.  Mine didn't.  But that was a while back....

Comment: @aparente001 It depends a lot on the type of student loan. A lot more people have private loans now, and I think it is only certain types of federal loans that come with subsidies like not accruing interest while a student.

Comment: @aparente001 The loans you don't have to pay interest on are being subsidized by the federal government, generally, and are a form of need-based (you have to qualify based on family income, not be disqualified for some legal reason, etc) financial aid: https://studentaid.ed.gov/sa/types/loans/subsidized-unsubsidized The limit is $23,000 lifetime as an undergraduate, and graduate students no longer qualify for subsidized loans at the US federal level in any way. So not only have college costs risen, and thus the need for loans, but the effective cost of the loans themselves have gone up.

Comment: Well, don't forget about Master's students who usually have to pay their own way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are underestimating the number of graduate students who do not get any form of financial support. Like you said, most students in STEM or engineering PhD programs full receive full support. PhD students in humanities/social sciences departments are less funded compared to STEM students, but at least are given tuition remissions.

On the other hand, majority of MA students in *any* discipline generally receives no support. Then there is MBA students, law students, doctoral residents etc. They are the ones who make up a big portion of all graduate students and most of them have to get student loan to complete their graduate programs.

For example, a typical law school graduate would end up with 60k-100k+ loans at the time they pass the bar and get a job.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's silly to talk about cumulative debt, adding undergraduate debt to whatever a student might accrue as a grad student, and instead ask whether grad students accumulate more as grad students than undergrads do as undergrads.  And the answer, I'm pretty sure, varies enormously across fields.  Many students at top law schools borrow the entire cost of their education (say $220K as of a year or two ago), but they expect to earn enough to pay down that debt and make it worthwhile. Some places offer fellowships, even covering the total cost over those 3 years, to attract excellent students.  But most are borrowing up to their noses.  Same for med schools I imagine.  In arts & sciences, students often can get fellowships or funding as research assistants or teaching assistants.  When I got a PhD in computer science I didn't borrow any money as a grad student.

Bottom line: I think the typical debt load in certain fields (law, medicine, maybe business) is higher per/year than undergrads -- who generally can't borrow the entire cost -- and in others it is (close to) nonexistent.

Comment: Why is it silly? It seems more silly to me to consider graduate debt alone, when the student has to repay both forms of debt and undergraduate debt isn't forgiven for being a graduate student. Debt-per-year values also don't tell you much, because regardless of the length of a program, $20k debt after 1 year and $20k debt after 5 years is still $20k+interest to pay back after graduating.

Comment: My point was that the question started with "A student advocate at my institution recently claimed that grad students have more debt than undergrads.".  Of course they have "at least as much" if they start with whatever the undergrad debt is.  So if you're going to compare whether it's more or less, I think the only reasonable comparison is the amount accrued as one or the other.  Of course the earlier debt carries over.

Comment: Not necessarily true, the faulty logic there is assuming that undergrad debt for undergrads bound for grad school is equal to undergrad debt for those who aren't.

Comment: @BryanKrause, you're not following me.  I'm saying that anyone who enters grad school with debt only adds to that debt, or gets a free ride.  And that therefore adding undergraduate to their graduate debt overstates the response to the quoted statement.  If the question is, do undergrads who go to grad school accrue more undergrad debt than undergrads who don't, that is a different question.  In any case, I think this argument is moot.  As someone else commented under the question said, and I did, certain grad disciplines totally dwarf ugrad $ and others don't add.

Comment: Had my RA stipend been livable, I wouldn't have taken on additional debt during grad school. It wasn't.

Comment: @HEITZ, I'm sure this varies from department to department, school to school, and region to region.  Some may borrow to supplement RAships, or maybe they can't get enough support from the school for the entire duration of study.  But I think there is still a big difference between academic studies and specialties like law/medicine.  In my case I got tuition paid, plus a small stipend that was barely enough to live on.  In my daughter's case (law school), she gets to borrow both, and it ain't cheap...

Comment: @FredDouglis No, I do understand what you are saying, I just disagree with your characterization of it as "silly" - likely the factor that impacts the actual people involved, the students, is the affordability of their debt payments upon graduation. Graduate students and undergraduate students are not simply a different longitudinal sample of the same group of students. The OP had assumed that grad students would have had less undergraduate debt than average before hearing the statistics, and was wondering about the source/background of those statistics.

Comment: (besides that, I fully agree that area of study is a huge factor in debt load)

Comment: @BryanKrause, the question **Do undergraduate students typically have more student debt than graduate students have** is not the same as the one you think was asked, which sounds like **Do graduate students start with less undergraduate debt than students who do not go on to graduate school**.  An interesting question to be sure, but personally I don't think it's what was asked.

Comment: No, that is not the question I think was asked, but the OP specifically said in the question "This surprised me, because I would expect that typical grad students are the kind of student that would be able to gather more financial aid (scholarships, awards, fellowships, etc.) during their time as an undergrad than typical undergrads" - indicating that they consider undergrad debt as at least *part* of the debt carried by graduate students. The question **Do graduate students take on more debt per year than undergraduate students?** is not what was asked, either.

Answer (score 0):

While the article "[The Shame of PhD Debt](https://theprofessorisin.com/2014/01/22/the-shame-of-ph-d-debt/)" does not directly answer the question of whether graduate or undergraduate students have more debt, you may well find it a worthwhile read because it explores some of the reasons for accruing significant debt in graduate programs. You may find the [surveys](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0An-UdyZNOVCQdGVJN3hWU0EtbjRwR2t1R1JLR19Hd0E&usp=sharing) referred to in this article especially useful for thinking about and understanding debt at all levels in higher education. These surveys contain self-reported data from graduate students across disciplines, who explain how much debt they accrued at undergraduate/graduate levels and why.

According to the data from the second survey (which I *strongly* encourage you to have a look at), there is great variety among amounts of debt even within fields. Although it does appear that 'hard science' types are more likely to escape both graduate and undergraduate education with less debt than arts & humanities students, I found it surprising that many of the people with zero debt were from arts, humanities, and social science fields. Also, most of the people with zero debt did not necessarily have terrific scholarships. Rather, they were independently wealthy or had a spouse/partner supporting them. Again, I suggest you look at the data, yourself. (If anyone feels so compelled, perhaps we could discuss our thoughts on the data in chat to avoid clogging the comments section.)

Note: I think it is worth pointing out that some people conceptualize time in graduate school as 'lost wages,' and if a student also has unpaid undergraduate debt, that debt continues to grow during graduate school. Lost wages and loan interest could mean that many graduate students end up with far more debt that some undergraduates, though I am sure this varies greatly by field. I cannot find a source that directly answers your original question, but according to the [Institute for College Access and Success](http://ticas.org/posd/map-state-data), 68% of (public/non-profit) college seniors in the U.S. left undergraduate programs with debt, with an average of $30,000. This should provide some frame of reference for thinking about the accrual of debt through undergraduate into graduate school.